# Google App Engine-Java: HTML Error 403: Configuration Solution Thread

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, windows-7

**GAE: Java: Windows 7 CONFIG** :

> I am trying to test a basic HTML "Hello World" on GAE under Windows7/Java before getting into something more interesting.  however, when pasting 
>   `http://localhost:8888` into Chrome or IE =>throws ERROR 403`
>
> .  I have searched through the posted workable solutions for a couple days

**I want to make this a SOLUTION THREAD for many Google App Engine- Java coders**

> **Here are some of the recommended Solutions from other threads**:  tried, but not resolving my error 403.
>
> **(1)** Disabled my firewall/ virus protection/ reduced security to nothing
>   **(2)** ping "localhost" via cmd running as administrator 
>   **(3)** modified c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file to remove "::1" 
>   **(4)** proxy settings modified (IE Options->connections->lan settings->{checked} "use proxy > server for LAN && {checked}bypass proxy server for local addresses && (under ADVANCED-EXCEPTIONS} added "localhost" in the section 'do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with:
>   `'localhost'` **(5)** tried flushing dns via cmd
>    * Ipconfig  /flushdns *nbstat –R *nbstat –RR  *netsh int reset all * nets int ip reset * netsh winsock reset
>
> I like to understand the inner-workings- so this code is a skeletal to test the GAE configuration is dialed-in & working before I upload more. It seemed pretty easy according to the tutorial.
>
> As I am new to working with the GAE, I would greatly appreciate detail about why/how it's > not working/how your recommendation corrects the issue.  Thanks a lot GAE technical team.  You Rock!
>
> Signed: Tree@iTreeware.com

---

**INDEX.HTML**

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>  <body> <p> Hello World from TREEware! </br> 403 Error B Gone!</p> 
>  </body>
>  </html>
>
```

---

**WEB.XML**

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
> xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
>  
> </web-app>
```

---

**APPENGINE-WEB.XML**

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
>   <application>itreeware1</application>
>  <version>1</version>
> 
>   <!--
>     Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
>   -->
>   <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
> 
>   <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
>   <system-properties>
>     <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
>   </system-properties>
> 
>   <!--
>     HTTP Sessions are disabled by default. To enable HTTP sessions specify:
> 
>       <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
> 
>     It's possible to reduce request latency by configuring your application to
>     asynchronously write HTTP session data to the datastore:
> 
>       <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />
> 
>     With this feature enabled, there is a very small chance your app will see
>     stale session data. For details, see
>     http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions
>   -->
> 
> </appengine-web-app>
```

### >

**LOG**

> ---

```
> Jun 12, 2013 8:26:39 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader 
> readAppEngineWebXml
> INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Organize4Joy\workspace\TreeApp1\war\WEB-\
> INF/appengine-web.xml
> Jun 12, 2013 8:26:39 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader 
> readConfigXml
> INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Organize4Joy\workspace\TreeApp1\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
> Jun 12, 2013 8:26:39 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager 
> setSystemProperties
> INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Program > Files\Google\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.1\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-
> INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\Organize4Joy\workspace\TreeApp1\war\WEB-
> INF\appengine-web.xml'
> Jun 12, 2013 8:26:39 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
> INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
> Jun 13, 2013 1:26:40 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
> INFO: jetty-6.1.x
> Jun 13, 2013 1:26:42 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
> INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
> Jun 13, 2013 1:26:42 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
> INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:8888/
> Jun 13, 2013 1:26:42 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
> INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
> Jun 12, 2013 8:26:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
> INFO: Dev App Server is now running
> Jun 12, 2013 8:27:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet 
> doGet
> WARNING: No file found for: /favicon.ico
> Jun 12, 2013 8:27:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet 
> doGet
> WARNING: No file found for: /favicon.ico
```

---

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A misplaced file here will also sometimes throw a 403.

Make sure that your `HTML` page is in the `war` folder and not `WEB-INF`, otherwise it might not be found.  You might expect this to result in a 404, but in this case, expect also a 403.

You could also make it easier for the application to find it by mapping its location as the `welcome file` in your `web.xml`.  You can do this by including the following code within the `web-app` tags:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I moved my index.html to the war folder & all executed as expected.